# Differentiate one function for another

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two functions

$f_1 = \cos(\omega t + \theta)$ and

$f_2 = \sin(\omega t + \theta)$

and want to differentiate $f_1$ for $f_2$ like this:

$f' = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial f_2}$

Is it correct to do the following:

$f' = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial f_2}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial f_2} = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\cdot (\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x})^{-1}$

Which would result in $tan(\omega t + \theta)$?

I can't find any proof whether it is correct or not. Also the step where I differentiate the inverse seems to be wrong, since sin(x) is not explicitly invertible, though I could invert it in an area $[-\pi; \pi]$.

Comment: I think for this case what you did is ok. You are right to be cautious, but I don't see a problem here. As a check, you can use $$f_1^2+f_2^2=1$$ to explicitly find $f_1(f_2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

As we know, d(f1)/dx = -wsin(wt + θ) 
and d(f2)/dx = wcos(wt+ θ)

now you can just divide these two equations, eliminating dx

d(f1)/d(f2) = -tan(wt+θ)

you arent really finding the differential of the inverse here, you are just taking the reciprocal of differentiation of the sin function